# Lookups that span relationships User

Tags: django, django-views

I have model Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ......
```

First I have tried to get all post for the current user using the following code and things worked alright

```
def get_queryset(self):
          return models.Post.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username"))
```

Everything worked as expected for the code above.

BUT when I tried to retrieve all users with posts that was created before certain date. I followed django documentation which is very clear and had this function.

```
def get_queryset(self):
         return User.objects.filter(post__created_at__lte='2019-01-01')
```

But django seems to expect only User fields not another model name and fields because the error I got is expecting User fields 
the error is:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'post' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, group, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, posts, user, user_groups, user_permissions, username.
```

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Post` model you have defined

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

Your related name is `posts`.

So just update your code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.filter(posts__created_at__lte='2019-01-01 00:00:00+05')
```

In `2019-01-01 00:00:00+05` +05 is TZ.

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: that doesn't work..this was first thing I have tried..thanks though

Comment: what was the result of that ?

Comment: page not found(404)..No user found matching the query...although I have users matching my condition

Comment: check your '2019-01-01' format.  Might be diff format is different in database

Comment: you have defined `DateTimeField` in model and you are just passing `date` in query.

Comment: let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

You specified the `related_name` to be `posts`.

And in the error message that you have, Django actually tells you that there is a field called `posts`.